# Twilio Fax detection

Tags: python, twilio, fax

I'm using Twilio API to detect if a remote number is answered by a human/voicemail or auto attendant.
There are few cases in which some of my numbers are answered by Fax machines.
I'm downloading the recording once call is connected, but want to know if Twilio can detect Fax tone and return result in call status method or I may need to find a way "listen" and detect Fax tones from a .wav file programmatically (Using FAX 2100-Hz frequency)

Example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnR03_10ai4

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using the [answering machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#handling-outcomes) to handle this at all?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I saw the feature but shows "deprecated" in documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#handling-outcomes. Not sure if it will be a good solution in the long run. Will give it a try. Does Twilio plans to continue with this feature in future releases?

Comment: Oh, there's a good point. I had not seen that! It might be worth trying for the time being. Otherwise, I'd recommend either using a [whisper to screen the call](https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/talk-to-an-agent/2.html) or doing something with the recording afterwards, as you suggested.